# Get List of Users having access to given AWS Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a situation where I want to get a list of users who has permission to given AWS Resource.

Comment: What "AWS Resource"? EC2 instances, S3 objects, SNS topics, Lambda function? Each AWS service manages its own resources. Also, permissions are typically assigned via IAM permissions that need to be parsed to determine access. Please edit your question to add more details rather than answering via a comment. Also, please include more details about _why_ you are seeking this information because there might be an alternative means of satisfying your goals.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I have found solution for my usecase at https://github.com/nccgroup/PMapper.